# SQL Query If more than one contact I only want the first listed

Tags: sql, if-statement

I am trying to write a query that joins residents emergency contacts names and phone numbers however we have several types of emergency contacts they can list.

For example: they can list emergency contact, responsible party, Power of Attorney.

I am wanting to pull back Responsible party. But some have 2 responsible parties listed and some have none and only an emergency contact.

How do I get just the first listed Responsible party and or if they do not have a responsible party listed grab the emergency contact but only 1 not several if they list more than one emergency contact.

```
Resident Name   Contact Name    Phone          Contact Type
----------------------------------------------------------------
Jane Doe        John Smith      999-999-9999   Responsible Party
Jane Doe        Patrick Star    999-888-8888   Responsible Party
```

I only want one of those Responsible Party not both

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements, so we can reproduce your issue. Right now I have no idea what your table structure is, particularly for how emergency contacts are stored.

Comment: We need a bit more info before we can help. Can you post the query you're running that's not returning the results you want?

Comment: Given that relational databases have no concept of record order, what is your definition of the first listed responsible party - how are you ordering them?

Comment: So to answer the last question about how I am ordering them?  I am not ordering them.  I am just asking to pull residents that have a contact listed.  The problem is the software system allows there to be several listed as the same contact type and I only want one returned.  If they list 5 people as contacts as their contact type is responsible party I don't want all 5 returned.  I just want one I don't really care which one, prefer the first line because that would tend to be a more important family member. Hope that makes sense

Comment: The query itself is joining 3 tables but in that I wrote a Where statement.  Where contacts.contact_type ='ResponsibleParty'  can it say something like IF there are more than 1 listed responsible party for the resident only grab 1? or grab the first one listed for that resident?